# Where can i find Django get_absolute_url?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have django 1.9.12 installed. Where is now get_absolute_url from django.db.models.base ? How can i find it? I tried to find it in django.db.models.base, but can't find it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with it? its still part of the model

Answer (score 2):

It's not a method that is pre-defined.

You need to implement it in your model class.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url):

> Define a `get_absolute_url()` method to tell Django how to calculate the
>   canonical URL for an object. To callers, this method should appear to
>   return a string that can be used to refer to the object over HTTP.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> def get_absolute_url(self):
>     return "/people/%i/" % self.id
> ```